# Phonegap_saving user credentials

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, user-data

What would you recommend for using to store user's credentials with phonegap? I would like to avoid any external storage ...
And does anybody know more about security of storing it with localStorage? I know it is stored in web browser but is it protected in a context of the app (like in sandbox) or? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't save the credentials. Let the user write it down every time, or use a cookie with certain expiration date to keep the session, but storing credentials is a bad idea from a security point of view, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with that specially with the part of just using cookies, but maybe i will be forced to use it, so i am curious about the security aspect of saving the data within the browser using phonegap, is it protected additionally by something or ?

Comment: The only protection you'll get from localStorage is that the data is only viewable from the domain name it was created with. But I wouldn't  consider that a secured data..

Comment: what do you mean 'only viewable from the domain name'

Comment: If your application's url is "example.com", then only a request coming from example.com can read the data. But local applications created with phonegap use the domain "localhost", so I guess every other phonegap app can read your data, but I haven't test this.

Comment: And, of course, this doesn't matter if the user has access to the device and the file system where `localStorage` is stored. For example, on iOS, I can inspect the `localStorage` of any PhoneGap app -- period. And it's all human-readable. Whatever you do, *DO NOT STORE ANY SECURE INFORMATION IN `localStorage`*! The best place? Look at the keychain plugin: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.shazron.cordova.plugin.keychainutil. Even so, better to store session auth tokens that can be expired than actual passwords. Best to simply never store the information at all.

Comment: All phonegap apps are sandboxed on the OS, just like any other app. Therefore the contents of `localStorage` are specific to the app. But not safe from prying eyes as in the above comment.

Comment: keychain plugin is only for iOS (?!), and i have to deploy it to both android and iOS device